# Custom CSS for title fields of Articles specified in content creation

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

Custom CSS for title fields of Articles specified in content creation

As an example, I have a view that displays my latest 10 articles but want the titles to be different colours. I want these colours to be determined based on what I input at the content creation form, whether it be in a separate field or by defining/attaching a specific class to each new Article.

Is there a way to do this or a better solution to my problem available? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this as a hack solution for the interim until I find a better solution to implement. The following will apply a blue background to all articles in the front page feed view that have the title 'First Article'.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span class="views-field-title">
        <a href="/articles/first-article">
            First Article
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.ApplySpecificTitle = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $('span.views-field-title a:contains("First Article")').parent().addClass('article-title-first');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS:**

```
.views-field-title {
    background: #CCC; /* Default background */
}
.article-title-first {
    background: blue;
}
```

*Note: This is probably far from the most graceful solution but it works for my instance as I won't be adding new articles very often.*

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest and quickest implementation I'd suggest you create a array in your THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) in  template.php:

```
<?php
$vars['color_cls'] = array( 
    'red',
    'blue',
    'yellow'
);
?>
```

Then you could simply randomly address those in your node.tpl.php and print them as a class in your node, something like this:

```
<div class="node <?= $color_cls[array_rand($color_cls)]; ?>">
```

You could also make the color_cls array associative and give them, for example, priorities:

```
<?php
$vars['color_cls'] = array( 
    'critical' => 'red',
    'important' => 'blue',
    'normal' => 'yellow'
);
?>
```

And ofcourse, then you just style them with your CSS. I'm assuming you do know how to style the classes, so I'll leave out the CSS  bit.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give this a try. Is there no module that handles this sort of thing?

Comment: Well... The somewhat limited information you gave in the initial question, made it look like you are trying to randomly assign colors to your nodes. So this would make it a theme-level issue, so I would do this all at theme level. If you are actually trying to assign severities to nodes or something of that nature, I'd suggest you make a field with a Priority dropdown for that with a few options that you would select on creation/edit of the node. Then print the values of that field in the `class` attribute of the node's div.

Comment: No, I have a view listing all articles in lots of 10, I want to change the colour of their title field at will. I was thinking if I could add a class to each particular article content then I could alter it like that.